Doubt in a proposition from Fulton's Algebraic Curves, section 5.5 (some criteria for Noether's condition)
I was reading section on Max Noether’s Fundamental Theorem in Fulton's Algebraic Curves and came across the following proposition which gives some sufficient criteria for Noether's condition to hold (we say that Noether’s Conditions are satisfied at $P$ with respect to $F, G$, and $H$, if $H_* \in (F_*,G_*) \subseteq \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)$):
Let $F, G, H$ be plane curves, $P \in F \cap G$. Then Noether’s conditions are
satisfied at $P$ if any of the following are true:

$F$ and $G$ meet transversally at $P$, and $P \in H$.
$P$ is a simple point on $F$, and $I(P,H \cap F) \ge I(P,G \cap F)$.
$F$ and $G$ have distinct tangents at $P$, and $m_P(H) \ge m_P(F)+m_P(G)−1$.

The proof for the second criteria proceeds as follows:

$I(P,H \cap F) \ge I(P,G \cap F)$ implies that $ord^F
_P(H) \ge ord^F_P(G)$, so $\overline{H_*} \in (\overline{G_*}) \subseteq
\mathcal{O}_P(F)$. Since $\mathcal{O}_P(F)/(\overline{G_*}) \cong \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)/(F_*, G_*)$, the residue of $H_*$ in $\mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)/(F_*, G_*)$ is zero, as desired.

Here $ord^F_P(G)$ is defined only when $F$ is irreducible and $P$ is simple point on $F$, in that case $\mathcal{O}_P(F)$ is a DVR and it is the order of residue of $G_*$ in $\mathcal{O}_P(F)$. According to Fulton's definition, plane curves need not be irreducible. So, it makes me think that we should require $F$ to be irreducible. From this criteria, we have a corollary (which we get by applying Noether's theorem):

If all the points of $F \cap G$ are simple points of $F$, and $H•F \ge G•F$,
then there is a curve $B$ such that $B•F = H•F −G•F$.

From what I mentioned above, I felt that $F$ needed to be irreducible. I was satisfied with this until I read this proposition in the next section:

(Pascal's Theorem) If a hexagon is inscribed in an irreducible conic, then the opposite sides meet in collinear points.

The text sketches an argument as follows: Let $C$ be three sides, $C′$ the three opposite sides, $Q$ the conic, and apply a result obtained through the corollary mentioned above. Here $C$ (resp. $Q$, $C'$) plays the role of $F$ (resp. $G$, $H$). So I cannot assume that $F$ is irreducible.
How can we modify the argument so that it works for general $F$?

This is Fulton's text https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

I think this is why Fulton takes $F$ to be irreducible WLOG. Let us write $F$ as $F_1F_2\ldots F_k$ where each $F_i$ is irreducible (note each $F_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial). Since $P$ is simple point of $F$, $F_i(P)=0$ for a unique $i$ (say $F_1(P)=0$ without loss of generality). So $I(P,H \cap F_i) = I(P,G \cap F_i) = 0$ for $2 \le i \le k$. This (along with the hypothesis $I(P,H \cap F) \ge I(P,G \cap F)$ and property of intersection number) implies that $I(P,H \cap F_1) \ge I(P,G \cap F_1)$. Now we can repeat Fulton's argument to get $H_*=aF_1{_*}+bG_*$ where $a,b \in \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)$. Let us recall what $F_*$ actually means. Choose a line $L$ not passing through $P$ (we can easily show existence of such a line). $F_*$ simply means $\frac{F}{L^n}$ where $n=deg(F)$. Let $n_i=deg(F_i)$, $m=deg(G)$ and $l=deg(H)$.
Note $F_i(P) \not = 0$ for $i \ge 2$ and so $\frac{L^{n_i}}{F_i} \in \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)$ for $i \ge 2$. Combining the above facts: $$\frac{H}{L^l}=a\frac{F_1}{L^{n_1}}+ b\frac{G}{L^{m}}=a\frac{L^{n_2+...+n_k}}{F_2F_3 \ldots F_k}\frac{F}{L^n}+ b\frac{G}{L^{m}}$$
Note $a\frac{L^{n_2+...+n_k}}{F_2F_3 \ldots F_k} \in \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)$ and so $H_* \in (F_*,G_*) \subseteq \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb P^2)$.
